# What is wrong with my sentence palindrome code (C++)?

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling, palindrome, sentence

The below code is of a sentence palindrome checker. I'm a newbie programmer so I'm having a hard time debugging this code. It's showing incorrect output.
For example, if the sentence is "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
It's giving false as a result instead of true. (Blank spaces and punctuations are to be neglected.)

---

```
#include <iostream>

class Solution
{
public:
    bool isPalindrome(std::string s)
    {
        int l, i;
        i = 0;
        l = s.length();

        while (i <= (l - 1))
        {

            if (s[i] == ' ' || ispunct(s[i]) == true)
                i++;

            else if (s[l - 1] == ' ' || ispunct(s[l - 1]) == true)
                l--;

            else if (tolower(s[i]) == tolower(s[l - 1]))
            {
                l--;
                i++;
            }

            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Solution s;
    const std::string text = "Panama";

    std::cout << s.isPalindrome(text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First create a simple `main` function which uses your class to pass the failing sentence. Then you can use a debugger to step through the code, statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. I also recommend that you create temporary variables to store intermediate results of functions calls, like for example `auto temp1 = ispunct(s[i]);` and then use `temp1 == true` instead of `ispunct(s[i])==true`.

Comment: You probably need to replace the `if` statements with `while` loops. But do learn how to debug by yourself.

Comment: Please avoid comparing boolean expressions (in this case, represented as an `int`) to `true`. It's useless and can (and does in this case) damage your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is very likely that the [character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification) (like e.g. `ispunct`) does *not* return a `bool` result.

They return an `int` whose value can be *any* non-zero value for "true".

That means the condition like `ispunct(s[i]) == true` might actually be `false` for punctuation characters.

You need to use e.g. `ispunct(s[i]) != 0` (or just plain `ispunct(s[i])`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

And also, that is not how one checks for palindrome. I suggest the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    for (auto i = 0, j = str.size() - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        if (//check for punctuation) {

        }
        else if (str.at(i) != str.at(j)) {
            //not a palindrome
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```